# How do I make my callback function include setTimeout, accept parameters and also include error handling?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm creating a callback addition function, the operation needs to have a delay using `setTimeout` of 100ms.
I have the `add` function which I'm not sure how I can "import" into my `addCallback`:

```
// Validating that the input is numbers
function numbersValidation(number1, number2) {
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new TypeError('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
}
// Add function
function add(number1, number2) {
  numbersValidation(number1, number2);
  return number1 + number2;
}
// Callback function
const addCallback = (err, number1, number2, add) => {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
  return setTimeout(() => {
    add(number1, number2);
  },
  100);
};
```

I thought that with a callback I need to insert my `add` function as a parameter, but my IDE says that `add` has already been declared in the upper scope.
I also should use the "error-first" callback, ergo I added the `err` at the beginning, but I'm not sure if it works like that or not.
Can someone please pinpoint me in the right direction for the above to work?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback based function should have a callback as the last parameter, and generally does not return anything:

```js
function someFunction(arg1, arg2, callback) { ... }
```

Inside the function, you will call `callback(error)` if there is any error, or `callback(null, something)` is things go fine.

Putting it all together:

```js
// Validating that the input is numbers
function numbersValidation(number1, number2) {
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new TypeError('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
}

function add(number1, number2) {
  numbersValidation(number1, number2);
  return number1 + number2;
}

const addCallback = (number1, number2, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      const result = add(number1, number2);
      callback(null, result);
    } catch(error) {
      callback(error);
    }
  }, 100);
};


addCallback(2, 3, (error, sum) => {
  if (error) {
     console.log('error summing numbers', error);
     return;
  }
  // do something with the sum
});
```

Comment: _"...and generally does not return anything"_? `Array.prototype.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.find()`, `.sort()`, `.filter()`, ...

Comment: @moonwave99 omg thank you so much! I had no idea you could structure it like this. I have one question, I do not understand the part where you do `callback(null, result);` or `callback(error)`. Spontaneously it seems like you're calling a function called `callback` which has not been defined somewhere, it has only been passed as a parameter. So how does one interpret these lines? If everything is fine in the try block, then callback returns null and result? Or?

Comment: @Andreas those are not callback based functions ^^ the functions passed to map/reduce/etc are predicates executed on every entry of the array, not functions that return the result of the whole process. The counter example is `setTimeout`, that expects a callback _and_ returns the timer ID.

Comment: @AndreiVarzari see the example below, where `addCallback` is called with 3 params - the two numbers and an anonymous function, that is the `callback` parameter inside the function.

Comment: @moonwave99 _"In computer programming, a callback or callback function is any reference to executable code that is passed as an argument to another piece of code"_ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))) -> Any function passed as argument that then is executed from the function it has been passed into is a "callback"